# Installation troubles... Compiling from source code on a mac book pro

Tags: mac, installation, compiling

So, I've tried to follow the instructions in /doc/build-osx.md

I installed the dependencies using Homebrew

```
brew install autoconf automake berkeley-db4 libtool boost miniupnpc openssl pkg-config protobuf qt5
```

Just to verify if I run this command again, I get the following:

```
Warning: autoconf-2.69 already installed
Warning: automake-1.15 already installed
Warning: berkeley-db4-4.8.30 already installed
Warning: libtool-2.4.6 already installed
Warning: boost-1.60.0_1 already installed
Warning: miniupnpc-1.9.20151008 already installed
Warning: openssl-1.0.2e_1 already installed
Warning: pkg-config-0.29 already installed
Warning: protobuf-2.6.1 already installed
Warning: qt5-5.5.1_2 already installed
```

I then run :

```
 ./autogen.sh
```

which is fine,

Then I run:

```
./configure --with-gui=qt5
```

And after a lot of lines of checking... I get, the following

```
...
checking miniupnpc/upnperrors.h presence... yes
checking for miniupnpc/upnperrors.h... yes
checking for main in -lminiupnpc... (cached) yes
**configure: error: Qt dependencies not found**
```

Any ideas what I could to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I ran the `./configure` without the `-with-gui=qt5` option and the installation went through fine.

btw, this was on MAC OS X Yosemite (Version 10.10.5).